NextJS with Deck.GL and WKWebView on iOS 16
When I run DeckGL on WKWebView, the page does not render at all. When I've separated the code to lazy load, I got an error from NextJS 14: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. And I don't need to do a lot to crash the app. Just initializing a new IconLayer with new IconLayer crashes the app. Or just importing DeckGL like below:
export const MapComponent: FunctionComponent<MapComponentProps> = ({
  controllable = true,
}) => {
  const [viewState, setViewState] = useState(INITIAL_VIEW_STATE);

  return (
    <DeckGL
      initialViewState={viewState}
      controller={controllable}
    >
    </DeckGL>
  );
};

This is enough to get this error which comes from ./node_modules/@deck.gl/layers/dist/icon-layer/icon-layer.ts or ./node_modules/@deck.gl/core/dist/lib/deck.js depending what is initialized - either IconLayer or DeckGL component.
Currently, the only working solution I have is to ask users to update to iOS 17.
